# Rendering chart inside jsp without storing

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I have created a chart using JFreeChart inside a JSP. I want to render this chart in a webpage using JSP, without storing the image as JPEG/PNG file. This is in the google app engine environment which [does not support writing to disk](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#writefile).

I tried the following:

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage chartImage = targetChart.createBufferedImage(600,400);
ServletOutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
JPEGImageEncoder encoder= JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out1);
```

but ended up getting a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
```

BTW, java.awt is also not allowed in the app engine environment. What options do I have for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, the above JSP code is for JSP that's specified in `<img src="...">`, right?
Make sure you have no spaces / new lines **anywhere** outside of `<% %>` tags on that page, otherwise they'll be written to JspWriter which would prevent you from obtaining OutputStream. I'm pretty sure that's the problem you're having now.

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned the JfreeChart approach and used the Google Chart API to build the pie chart.Ex.

```
<IMG SRC="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chco=FF3300,66CC33&cht=p3&chl=A|B|C|D&chs=500x200&chd=t:10,40,30,20&chtt=Your%20Chart"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Flash based charts, like amcharts
http://www.amcharts.com/.
See my demos at

http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/amcharts/doc
I tested this under GAE and it worked fine.